# A Tale of Two Domain Names - One resolves the other fails

Tags: domain-name-system, router, local-area-network

I have setup two domains on a server local to my LAN.

The first one is registered with GoDaddy and resolves fine behind the router. 
The Second domain is using zoneedit.com to handle the dns settings and isn't resolving behind the router locally.  It is resolving outside of my lan though.

I can't figure out the issue... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an internal DNS server, or directly querying your ISP's DNS from inside your LAN? Is the zoneedit.com domain defined as a zone in your internal DNS? Can you post the output from your LAN for "dig +trace failingdomain.com" for the domain that is failing?

Comment: I am querying against my ISP's DNS

Comment: I'm running windows on all of my machines - what is the equivalent command for dig?

Comment: nslookup is roughly similar.

Comment: dig is extremely helpful for DNS troubleshooting. There's a guide for grabbing it on Windows from the BIND for Windows archive here: http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/dns-dig-on-windows/

Comment: Also, try setting your DNS to 4.2.2.4 or 8.8.8.8 from your internal LAN and let us know if that works

Comment: Going to have to worry about it monday.  time for bed

Answer (score 2):

So, second domain is correctly solved outside of your network, that means your DNS cache should be cleaned:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

from command line, and try again.